# NoMethodError in ... form_for is looking for the plural of the path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

```
<% form_for @contact ... %>
```

Is raising no method error. The issue is it is looking for 'contacts_path' , all I have [and want to keep] is 'contact_path'

Pluralizing it would be awkward and I would have to change all the links to the contact page which seems wrong.

What can I do to get form_for to not look for *s_path !

Thank you = )

Error log:

```
NoMethodError in Pages#contact

Showing /home/user/hipstershaadi/app/views/contact_mailer/_contact_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `contacts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f0f6002ac08>:0x007f0f6002f4b0>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1 <% form_for @contact do |f| %>
2
3 <% end %>
```

Comment: get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show', as: 'patient' something like this in routes.rb should do. I am not sure what you are doing as you don't show the form_for code . The error is complaining about Pages#contact action & you are defining `contact_path`?? quite contradicting... you should read the rails guides first I guess.

Answer (score 2):

`contacts_path` is the convention, if you are going to differ from the convention then as usual you will have to do more work. One way around this would be to specify the path yourself:

```
form_for @contacts, url: contact_path do |f|
```

But usually `contact_path` would be reserved for something that is already saved to the database, as in an update form.

`form_for` will automatically use `PUT contact_path(@contact)` if `@contact.persisted?` is true, otherwise it will use `POST contacts_path`. Maybe your issue is that you think `@contact` is saved but it actually isn't? Or are you just straying from the convention for some other reason?